# Same architecture but training in two different domains: what is it called?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, transfer-learning, domain-adaptation

I am trying to find the keyword (if there is any) for the technique in which we use the same deep learning architecture that works well in one domain and train it again in another domain to find out that the architecture (not the trained model) is suitable for both the domains. It is unlike the word "domain adaptation" in which you use the same architecture but train it in one domain and only test it in another domain. What I am referring to is that only the untrained architecture is the same and both the training and testing are done separately in two different domains.

Comment: this doesn't sound very different from seeing and SVM+associated hyper-parameters and using it for your own problem using only your data. So, I don't think it has a name.